# What's the difference between HTTP_URL, REQUEST_URI and these other IIS variables?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, iis-6, url-rewrite-module

I came across various `<rewrite>` rules and noticed there are a lot of variables that appear to be the same. The [IIS Server Variables documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx) isn't really helping, for example it doesn't explain any difference between `PATH_INFO` and `URL`, it doesn't even mention `REQUEST_URI` at all, etc.

```
{HTTP_URL}      = /path/to/file.ext?key=value
{PATH_INFO}     = /path/to/file.ext
{R:1}           = /path/to/file.ext
{REQUEST_URI}   = /path/to/file.ext?key=value
{UNENCODED_URL} = /path/to/file.ext?key=value
{URL}           = /path/to/file.ext
{URL_PATH_INFO} = /path/to/file.ext
```

Besides the query string, I haven't found any other differences so far. Are there other differences, and why do we have multiple variables with the same value?

Comment: Many of them only show different values when you serve specific URLs. For example, if input URL is `/path/to/file.ext/some_path_info`, then `PATH_INFO` and `URL` are clearly different. "I haven't found any other differences so far" is not surprising as usually unless you are an IIS extension author (ISAPI or other) you are not given enough exposure to all kinds of URL related knowledge. It is challenging to fully document all details behind, as only a tiny group of people care about that.

Answer (score 9):

I cannot answer completely to your question (because documentation is not clear) and I did some research about that. Here are my findings for some variables:

### `{REQUEST_URI}`

Returns exact URL that you requested. For example, if you have `default.aspx` file in the root and you will access your website root. Then:

- `{REQUEST_URI}` is an empty string
- `{PATH_INFO}`, `{HTTP_URL}`, `{UNENCODED_URL}` are all `/default.aspx`

### `{R:1}`

Returns a first match in your regexp. For example, if you match regexp is `part(.*)part(.*)part(.*)` and you will access url `/partApartBpartC`. Then:

- `{R:0}` is `partApartBpartC`
- `{R:1}` is `A`
- `{R:2}` is `B`
- `{R:3}` is `C`

### `{UNENCODED_URL}`

Returns the raw, unencoded URL. For example if you will access `/"asdasd"""""asdsa` Then:

- `{REQUEST_URI}` is `/"asdasd"""""asdsa`
- `{UNENCODED_URL}` is `/%22asdasd%22%22%22%22%22asdsa`

Comment: Are you sure the `UNENCODED_URL` contains encoded characters like `%22`?